# displaying results(subproject) as sublist and I want to filter the results based on selected project from drop down

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I created one form, in that 2 sections one is header(parent) and another one is child. In header section i created one field like project(Drop down) like netsuite, SFDC etc and in child section i created one more field like subproject. When I am selecting any project according into that subproject name should be display . Please any one can answer me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created form with Suitelet or from Custom Record Form ? [ Please elaborate ]

If you have created with Suitelet it's more easy to do  than the Netsuite's Standardized custom form..

Comment: I created using suitelets only

Comment: Please can u explain how to create that . I am not getting how to create

Answer (score 0):

First create a sublist using form.addSublist('custpage_subproj_lst','list','Sub Project List',null);  give type as list..
Add fields to list as many as columns required....make sure the field type from the subproject must match with column type...

Now Create client script but don't deploy it on anything...
Get that client scripts id Ex.  "customscript_client_script" and add the following immediately after creating form like...form.addScript("customscript_client_script");

Now once you added client script to that form...create the Field Change function and add it in client script...

Now in Client Scripts Field Change function, check for Project field change and remove all child level lines....

Now Create a search on subproject by filtering the project...and get the results and set line level values from that save search...

Comment: If there are no result in search you are getting on field change..it 'll definitely give you an error if type is list...  Better use inline editor and set each fields(columns) display type to disabled